# Mapping Hive partitions to existing folder structure with arbitrary partition subdirectory names

Tags: hive

I'm looking for a solution to a somewhat uncommon problem - generally what I want to achieve is to have partitions of Hive table mapped to specific folders that already exist and *should not be renamed* to fit default Hive partition naming convention.

Folder structure I have is the following:

```
<some path>/Daily/database/<partition subfolders by day>
<some path>/Weekly/database/<partition subfolders by day>
<some path>/Lifetime/database/<partition subfolders by day>
```

What I'd like to have is Period (Daily, etc.) folders being treated as partitions as well.

Now there are two problems:

- *database* subfolder between potential partition subdirectories
- Period folders should not follow *partition-name=partition-value* naming format

I guess the former could be solved by a terrible crutch of adding a dummy column with "database" value in all rows and partitioning by it as well.

Regarding the latter though I'm not sure if it's possible at all, and from what I was able to find it's not, at least in a sensible way. So I'm looking for an advice on this, or at least an expert confirmation it's not possible :)

If that helps my environment is Databricks platform and files are being saved in parquet format.